# How to restore an JPA Entity with ManyToOne relations

Tags: java, jpa, merge, entitymanager

I have an JPA entity (Person) with ManyToOne relation to an other entity (Addresses). Before an object may be used by the system, this one has to be approved by an supervisor. I store the original entity as a byte[] and make changes to the "working" entity and store it do the database. If this changes would not be approved I have to restore the original state. So I convert the stored original from the byte[] and merge it using entity manager to the database. All works fine, but if an new Address entity has been added to the "working" Person, this one is not removed from the database after merging the restored original. I know why it is so, but no how to solve my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

orphanRemoval=true on @ManyToOne solves the problem